# replace 1 or 2 rims/wheel if car hit a curb?

Tags: tires, car, wheels

My car hit a curb while I was parking two days ago; speed was lower than 15mph. Still, **the bent is noticeable in the front**, passenger's side,

[image: front-1]
[image: front-2]
[image: front-3]
[image: front-4]

and **less noticeable in the rear,** also passenger's side:

[image: rear-1]
[image: rear-2]

There appeared to be no difference in tire pressure yesterday. However, starting from today, I noticed that the front one has tire pressure 29-30, compared with 32 of others. My questions are

(1) Would you recommend that I replace the front one, or both?
(2) Are the tires okay?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might be losing air because of the buckled wheel, but get the tyre checked at a shop. Apart from being off topic, we can't see the whole tyre, and, it should be inspected by putting it on a ramp, spinning the wheel and looking for distortion.

Comment: Since you are losing air, you need to go to a shop anyway. The flange on the steel wheel is bent, and it's a moderate bend. That's probably where it is leaking from. I have bent flanges back before that were causing a leak, with mixed results. Resign to the fact that you probably need a new wheel. The cap is a cosmetic issue. The tires are fine, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying steel rim looks bent . Replace  steel rim and hub cap. Steel rims should be much less costly than an aluminum wheel. The shop may find tire damage.

Comment: Steel wheels are running over $150 these days. A cheap alloy wheel starts at $180, even cheaper online. Steels aren't that cheap anymore, thank you COVID.

Answer (score -3):

That's not your rim, wheel or tire.

It's your hub cap. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubcap

A hub cap is only decorative. It has no structural role. You can damage it as long as you want and it won't cause any danger. If it gets too damaged, you can buy new ones, or you can just cheap out, throw them away and use your car without hup caps.

As for your tires, tire health questions are usually off-topic because usually they show damage and only an expert at a tire shop can judge whether your tires are safe for using. However, when looking at your tires (the black rubber, the white plastic is the hub caps), I am happy to see that I absolutely see no damage at all. So this isn't an usual off-topic tire health question.

Comment: Rim damage is apparent to me in the first four pictures.

Comment: Isn't the wheel rim also distorted?

Comment: Rim has bent, trapping the hub cap.